# Is it possible to disable the iOS five finger touch handling from an app?

Tags: ios

We have a palm scanning app and occasionally putting the palm on the app gets read as a 5 finger pinch or opposite of pinch gesture, which exits the app. Is there some way we can make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had completely missed the multitasking gestures setting which solves this in our case.